# Python - creating a list with 2 characteristics bug

Tags: python, list, composition

The goal is to create a list of 99 elements. All elements must be 1s or 0s. The first element must be a 1. There must be 7 1s in total.

```
import random
import math
import time

# constants determined through testing                                                                                                       

generation_constant = 0.96

def generate_candidate():
    coin_vector = []
    coin_vector.append(1)
    for i in range(0, 99):
        random_value = random.random()
        if (random_value > generation_constant):
            coin_vector.append(1)
        else:
            coin_vector.append(0)
    return coin_vector

def validate_candidate(vector):
    vector_sum = sum(vector)
    sum_test = False
    if (vector_sum == 7):
        sum_test = True
    first_slot = vector[0]
    first_test = False
    if (first_slot == 1):
        first_test = True
    return (sum_test and first_test)

vector1 = generate_candidate()
while (validate_candidate(vector1) == False):
    vector1 = generate_candidate()
print vector1, sum(vector1), validate_candidate(vector1)
```

Most of the time, the output is correct, saying something like

> [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0,
>   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0,
>   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
>   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
>   0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0] 7 True

but sometimes, the output is:

> [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
>   0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
>   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
>   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
>   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] 2 False

What exactly am I doing wrong?

Comment: "constants determined through testing" that doesn't sound like a good direction to solve the problem.

Comment: That's true.. but this snippet is meant to use something called genetic algorithms that I was asked to implement.

Comment: Right, most of the time the function won't satisfy the constraints, but the while loop at the bottom is meant to re-run the function till they are met.

Comment: ye, I can see that but the better approach would be to generate 6 random distinct positions where to place 1s. Anyway, I can't see an error in your current code.

Comment: @clime upvote, I agree with you so much, that would eliminate a lot of potential errors

Answer (score 1):

The algorithm you gave works, though it's slow. Note that the ideal `generation_constant` can actually be calculated using the binomial distribution. The optimum is ≈0.928571429 which will fit the conditions 1.104% of the time. If you set the first element to 1 manually, then the optimum `generation_constant` is ≈0.93877551 which will fit the conditions 16.58% of the time.

The above is based on the binomial distribution, which says that the probability of having exactly *k* "success" events out of *N* total tries where each try has probability *p* will be *P*( *k* | *N*, *p* ) = *N*! * *p* ^ *k* * (1 - *p*) ^ (*N* - *k*) / ( *n*! * (*N* - *k*)). Just stick that into Excel, Mathematica, or a graphing calculator and maximize *P*.

***Alternatively:***

To generate a list of 99 numbers where the first and 6 additional items are 1 and the remaining elements are 0, you don't need to call `random.random` so much. Generating pseudo-random numbers is very expensive.
There are two ways to avoid calling `random` so much.

The most processor efficient way is to only call random 6 times, for the 6 ones you need to insert:

```
import random

# create vector of 99 0's
vector = [0 for i in range(99)]

# set first element to 1
vector[0] = 1

# list of locations of all 0's
indexes = range(1, 99)

# only need to loop 6 times for remaining 6 ones
for i in range(6):
    # select one of the 0 locations at random
    # "pop" it from the list so it can't be selected again
    # and set it's coresponding element in vector to 1.
    vector[indexes.pop(random.randint(0, len(indexes) - 1))] = 1
```

Alternatively, to save on memory, you can just test each new index to make sure it will actually set something:

```
import random

# create vector of 99 0's
vector = [0 for i in range(99)]

# only need to loop 7 times
for i in range(7):
    index = 0                          # first element is set to 1 first
    while vector[index] == 1:          # keep calling random until a 0 is found
        index = random.randint(0, 98)  # random index to check/set
    vector[index] = 1                  # set the random (or first) element to 1
```

The second one will always set the first element to 1 first, because `index = random.randint(0, 98)` only ever gets called if `vector[0] == 1`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not certain I understand your requirements, but here's what it sounds like you need:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import random

ones = [ 1 for i in range(6) ]
zeros = [ 0 for i in range(99 - 6) ]
list_ = ones + zeros
random.shuffle(list_)
list_.insert(0, 1)

print(list_)
print(list_.count(1))
print(list_.count(0))
```

HTH

Answer (score 0):

With genetic programming you want to control your domain so that invalid configurations are eliminated as much as possible.  The fitness is suppose to rate valid configurations, not eliminate invalid configurations.  Honestly this problem doesn't really seem to be a good fit for genetic programming.  You have outlined the domain. But I don't see a fitness description anywhere.

Anyway, that being said, the way I would populate the domain would be: since the first element is always 1, ignore it, since the remaining 98 only have 6 ones, shuffle in 6 ones to 92 zeros. Or even enumerate the possible as your domain isn't very large.

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling it is your use of sum(). I believe this modifies the list in place:

```
>>> mylist = [1,2,3,4]
>>> sum(mylist)
10
>>> mylist
[]
```

Here's a (somewhat) pythonic recursive version

```
def generate_vector():
    generation_constant = .96
    myvector = [1]+[ 1 if random.random() > generation_constant else 0 for i in range(0,99)]

    mysum = 0
    for a in myvector:
        mysum = (mysum + a) 

    if mysum == 7 and myvector[0]==1:
        return myvector
    return generate_vector()
```

and for good measure

```
def generate_test():
    for i in range(0,10000):
        vector = generate_vector()
        sum = 0
        for a in vector:
            sum = sum + a
        if sum != 7 or vector[0]!=1:
            print vector
```

output:

```
>>> generate_test()
>>>
```